# Wifi problem on x1 carbon

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lenovo

So almost everything works as it should with 12.04.2 on this x1 carbon, except for the wireless connection.

Basically, the network almost never works after the first connection. The typical behavior is:

1. Right after login, I select the ssid I'm interested in in the list in the network manager, and after a few seconds it reports that it connected. ifconfig seems to agree with that.
2. I try to ping something or access a page through the browser, which fails. 
   Sometimes it disconnects by itself after a few seconds. In which case I retry connecting in the network-manager, which never succeeds.
3. I disable then enable networking in the network manager (or flip the hardware wifi switch off and on again, or sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart), and then reconnect to my wifi.
4. it then works fine until next suspend or reboot.

So I don't mind if it's some sort of dirty hack, but if anyone had a trick to get it to work in less steps than that, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've just upgraded to 12.10 and it looks like this is now fixed for me. The connection acquired by network-manager is functional right from the start, no need to restart the network-manager service anymore. Same thing when coming out of suspend.

Thanks to whoever worked on nm bugs for 12.10. (a few other annoying quirks have been fixed too actually).

I'd be curious to know what was the origin of the problem though...

Answer (score 1):

The problem (have a look at the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1293569)) is caused by the WiFi driver iwlwifi with firmware version 22.24.8.0, which unfortunately comes with the default kernel. To check your WiFi driver firmware version, you can run `dmesg | grep "iwlwifi .* loaded firmware version"`.

In the newer kernel, the driver has been replaced with higher version.